# Dynamic SQL Stored Procedure 2nd result set

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, reporting-services, nested

I am working on a request to display selected test results from two tables via SSRS. I have developed the dynamic SQL to accomplish this but got stuck when running the stored procedure, as I only receive the first result set.

This stored procedure first queries a tag name table that is used to build columns for the second query... which retrieves the actual desired data. The SP returns the column names but does not return the needed second result set.

I realize this is an ugly solution but our IT group had no input into original database design, so now we're trying to do what we can to help.

Code:

```
DECLARE @cols as NVARCHAR(MAX), @query1 as NVARCHAR(MAX), @query2 as NVARCHAR(MAX),
@FLOATTABLE NVARCHAR(MAX), @TAGTABLE NVARCHAR(MAX),@startdate as NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@ENDDATE AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @results as NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @FLOATTABLE = 'dbo.TRW_TESTER_FLOATTABLE' --for testing purposes only
set @tagtable = 'dbo.TRW_TESTER_TAGTABLE' --for testing purposes only

Set @startdate='2013-12-05' -- for testing purposes only
Set @enddate='2013-12-31' -- for tesying purposes only

set @query2 = 'SELECT STUFF((SELECT  DISTINCT   '','' +
QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,TagName),' 
+ '''"'') FROM ' + @TAGTABLE + ' FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,1,'''')'

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @query2, @Cols OUTPUT


Set @query1 = 'SELECT  DISTINCT DateAndTime, Millitm,  ' + @cols + ' FROM ( select
T.DateAndTime, T.Millitm, N.TagName, T.Val from ' + @FLOATTABLE + ' T  LEFT JOIN ' + 
@TAGTABLE + ' N ON T.TagIndex=N.TagIndex WHERE T.DateAndTime Between '''+ @startdate +
''' AND '''+ @enddate +''')  x PIVOT (MAX(Val) for TagName IN (' + @cols + ')) p'

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @query1, @results OUTPUT
```

Comment: Print `@query1` and post the result, that might help.

Comment: If I run this with PRINT @QUERY1 I still only get a result set from the first query to execute (@QUERY2). What the heck am I doing wrong.. something silly, I imagine! Thanks...

Comment: According to [EXECUTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), If `the intent is to use the return values in other statements` then `You cannot execute a module by specifying OUTPUT for a parameter that is not defined as an OUTPUT parameter in the module.` I think it indicates that your @query2 should have @Cols defined as an OUTPUT parameter before executing it. See if this helps.

Comment: Also see if `sp_executesql` explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499) might help.

Comment: Thank you. I did try defining @cols as an OUTPUT and received the error 'Data Type is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter. Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters. Use current large object types instead.'. NVARCHAR(MAX) is listed as a valid LOB... so I'm not sure where to go next?

Thanks again!

Comment: Looked around some more and found this might be related to the client, so I executed the SP on SSMS and received this error :'Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Hmm...

Comment: Both the errors need to be fixed, so adding `@Cols` to the parameters of proc should fix one. Also by executing `@query1` without the `@results` param, the proc will automatically return the query result. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I am now using EXECUTE (@query) with the same error resulting when the SP is run from SSMS. The SP now uses 'Alter Procedure test2 (@COLS varchar(MAX) OUTPUT) in the first line. Thus, I'm still stuck on the error "Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.'. The only sp_executeSQL call is one that populates @COLS from a dynamic query:

Comment: Try this. Change the `@query2` to `SELECT @ColsOUT = STUFF...` and for execution use `EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @query2, '@ColsOUT varchar(MAX) OUTPUT' ,  @ColsOUT = @Cols OUTPUT`